# How to compare date/time on a form within the Scala Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, validation, playframework, jodatime

I'm adding validation for date options in a Scala form; there are optional date fields that allow a user to search between a specific date/time range, but the second date needs to be after the first date for a valid range.

At the moment this validation works:

```
val searchForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "ItemID" -> optional(text),
    "fromDate" ->  optional(jodaLocalDate("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss")),
    "toDate" -> optional(jodaLocalDate("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss")),
    "Class" -> optional(text),
    "Status" -> optional(text),
    "Group" -> optional(text),
    "Area" -> nonEmptyText,
    "Ordered" -> optional(text)
  )(SearchModel.apply)(SearchModel.unapply)
  verifying("Both or no dates must be selected. Date/Time range must be valid.", f => (f.fromDate.isEmpty && f.toDate.isEmpty)||
  ((f.fromDate.isDefined&&f.toDate.isDefined)&&f.fromDate.head.isBefore(f.toDate.head))))
```

But it only compares the dates and ignores the time section `HH:mm:ss`.

Is there a way to add time validation too? Should I be using a different validation method?

Comment: Does your html form definitely send the time portion too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you get the time section from the form, the Date calling `.before()` would definitely check on the time portion, too.

Try:

```
def validateDates(fromDate: Option[Date], toDate: Option[Date]): Boolean = {
  if(fromDate.isEmpty || toDate.isEmpty) false 
  else fromDate.get.before(toDate.get)
}
```

Then:

```
verifying("Both or no dates must be selected. Date/Time range must be valid.", f => validateDates(f.fromDate, f.toDate))
```

Edit:
Just realised this wouldn't pass if both date fields are empty, so a slight modification to `validateDates` would fix that:

```
def validateDates(fromDate: Option[Date], toDate: Option[Date]): Boolean = {
      if(fromDate.isEmpty && toDate.isEmpty) true 
      else if(fromDate.isEmpty || toDate.isEmpty) false 
      else fromDate.get.before(toDate.get)
    }
```